# Comando cp en linux, no entiendo porque no funciona

Tags: linux, consola, línea-de-comandos

Pretendo copiar el archivo /etc/hosts con ruta relativa en la carpeta "copia": /home/rafael/copia,  y tengo que hacerlo con ruta relativa. No entiendo porque no funciona mi comando. Gracias

```
rafael@SistemasUbuntu:~$ cp ../../etc/hosts /copia
cp: no se puede crear el fichero regular '/copia': Permiso denegado
```

Comment: Normalmente, solo el usuario `root` puede escribir en el directorio raiz, que es donde tú estás intentando crear `copia`.

Comment: Súmale que hay que ver si el usuario rafael tiene algún permiso para siquiera ver /etc/hosts... en resumen, `sudo` es el camino

Answer (score 1):

Hazlo con permisos root usando

```
sudo cp
```

Answer (score 0):

Si miras los permisos de `/etc/hosts`, veràs que probablemente sea propiedad de `root`, y que los otros solo tienen permiso de lectura, por lo que el usuario `rafael` si tiene permiso para leer los archivos.
Por ejemplo:

```
ls -l /etc/hosts
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 186 en  1  2023 /etc/hosts
```

Nos indica que pertenece al usuario `root`, con permiso `rw` (read write)
al grupo `root` con permiso `r` y que los otros tienen permiso `r`

El problema debe ser que el usuario `rafael` NO tiene permiso para escribir en `/copia` ya que seguramente no es el propietario y los otros no tienen permiso de escritura.

```
ls -ld /copia
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 en 1 12:00 /copia
```

Nos indica que pertenece a `root` con permiso `rwx` (read, write, eXecution)
al grupo `root` con permisos `rx`, y que los demás `rx`
La solución mas "normal" creo que seria hacer a `rafael` propietario de `/copia` haciendo:

```
sudo chown rafael /copia
```

O mejor aun, en caso que mas usuarios deban poder escribir en `/copia`,  crear un grupo de usuarios que tengan permiso para escribir en `/copia` (o usar el grupo de sistema `backup`)

```
sudo addgroup copia
sudo usermod rafel -aG copia
```

Y hacer al grupo propietario de `/copia` con permisos de escritura

```
sudo chgrp copia /copia
sudo chmod g+rwx /copia
```